Updates to most tables take 0.2ms, updates to a few take 13+ms. Why?
We run a pretty busy 20TB MySQL 8.0.34 running on AWS RDS on an r6i.8xlarge, and about 3 tables are showing slower-than-normal updates that are puzzling me.
Normal single-row UPDATE .. WHERE .. queries are sub-millisecond here, especially on our busiest tables that receive ~500 of those per second.
Single-row UPDATE .. WHERE id = ? to 3 of our tables are running in 12-25ms, and making their way to the top time-consuming queries, even tho they run 25 times per second for each table.
At this rate, slow updates present a threat: if they grow in frequency, they risk clogging our DB.
Details on our server:

Runs on <25% CPU usage at peak
Has a large redo log file (5GB)
Buffer pool hit rate close to 100% on all buffer pools
Runs file per table

What I've examined so far hasn't helped me draw any conclusions:



Factor
Slow UPDATEs
Fast UPDATEs




Rows examined
1
1


Update changes indexed field or FK?
No
No


Triggers?
None
None


Indexes used in WHERE clause?`
Only Primary Keys
Some secondary Indexes


Table file formats?
All Barracuda
Some Antelope, some Barracuda


Evidence of fragmentation?*
<1% Data Free
Sometimes 17% Data Free (could be fragmented*)


Column types involved
One int, one datetime
Multiple ints and datetimes


Presence of varchar/text
Yes for 2 out of 3, but not touched by update
No


Performance at low vs high traffic
Goes from 5ms up to 25ms
Goes from 0.1ms to 0.2ms




* Bill Karwin explained in a comment that there is no way to measure fragmentation:

data_free does not measure database fragmentation. It only measures whole extents (64 contiguous pages) that are empty. It does not measure extents in which only some pages are empty, nor does it measure partially filled pages. There is effectively no way to detect those types of fragmentation in InnoDB.


Any pointers on how I could diagnose this further would be deeply appreciated. Most questions about slow updates deal with multi-second updates, so finding help has been really hard.
Anonymized schemas for the tables and SQL for the update queries
https://gist.github.com/omnibs/7afbe08dc2743cb72e333dda5f578c12
Additional details
Explain for the UPDATE queries
UPDATE `SLOW_A` SET `f` = ? , `g` = ? , `h` = ? WHERE `id` = ? AND `e` = ?;


UPDATE `SLOW_B` SET `k` = ? , `j` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;


UPDATE `SLOW_C` SET `i` = ? , `h` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;


UPDATE `FAST_A` SET `n` = ? , `e` = ? , `k` = COALESCE ( `k` , ? ) , `d` = COALESCE ( `d` , ? ) , `h` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;


UPDATE `FAST_B` SET `d` = ? WHERE `a` = ? AND `b` = ? AND `c` = ?;



Our database handles high throughput, and those simple updates taking 25ms are making their way to the top 3 time-sinks at peak traffic. This is what's hard about this. Everyone looking for help on the internet is dealing with seconds-long queries. We need queries to be sub-millisecond. We run a high throughput system that's sensitive to latency, has daily hiccups. We do our best to keep it under control, which involves keeping an eye on and trying to optimize any outliers we spot.
